# QuickBook desktop integration with Node.js

Tags: node.js, quickbooks

I want to integrate quickbook desktop with node, As i don't see any sdk for integrating quickbook desktop with node.

So please tell me how to integrate quickbook desktop with node.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply use the sdk with node because you would need a desktop application to communicate with QuickBooks. You need to use the QuickBooks Web Connector. I don't have experience connecting node with the web connector but I found this from a quick google search. https://github.com/johnballantyne/qbws

Unlike an API connection where you make requests, the QBWC makes requests to a SOAP server you will have to create.